# Why does the function run once when I put this.onclick=' ';?

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="#" onclick="addP(); this.onclick='';">See more</a>
```

Why does the function run once when I put this.onclick=' ';?

Comment: if you want to call more than one function you can use like this: onclick="one();tow();three();"

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. `HTMLElement.prototype.onclick` should also not be used. Use the `once` property in `addEventListener` instead or use `removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 3):

When you clicked the link.

1. It calls `addP`.
2. It removes onclick handler.

Now the actual HTML looks like

```html
<a href="#" onclick="addP();">See more</a>
```

To fix this remove `onclick=''` part in the onclick attribute.

```js
let addP = () => alert('you clicked the link')
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="addP();">See more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `this.onclick='';` because when the o'clock event (`addP`) Is over, it removes the the click event handler. So there are 2 methods for you :

---

**Method 1**
use javascript & html like so :

HTML :

```html
<a href="#" id="seeMore">See more</a>
```

Javascript :

```js
document.getElementById('seeMore').addEventListener('click', function() {
    addP();
});
```

---

---

**Method 2**
only using html

```html
<a href="#" onclick="addP();">See more</a>
```

---